# Android: Detecting long key press when screen is off

Tags: java, android

How can a long key press (volume keys) be detected in Android when the screen is off? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not certain... but have you taken a look at services? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I have not looked, I wanted to this this without services, but it probably will not work otherwise. Thanks

Comment: Your application will be paused if the screen is not awake, so I don't think this would be possible without services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. The only thing that could possibly detect a long press of a volume button is a foreground activity. This also assumes that the device has hardware volume buttons, and not all devices do.